# Alter table via command line

Tags: mysql, linux, alter-table

I need to alter a table (to change the length and type of a column) of a MySQL database.

The problem is that I need to do this from the command line (in Linux) and I don't really know how.

Can anyone help me?

I have root ssh access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

Login to mysql:

```
mysql -u username -p;
```

enter mysql password

```
use databasename;

ALTER TABLE `tablename`
MODIFY COLUMN `columnname`  varchar(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `previouscolumnname`;
```

The varchar(200) bit is where you would enter the column type and value length  like int(11) etc

Remember to be careful changing field types if the table contains data as it may empty the field or cut it down to the new length specified.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to update per your username, database, tablename and type/length:

```
mysql -u username -p
use database;
alter table `tablename` modify column `columnname` varchar(512);
```

Comment: Tried but it just gives me the posibility to append another line ore something. How do I commit the changes.

Comment: if you use a semicolon as in the example your alter should be executed. are you sure you have ; at the end of the alter?

Comment: make sure to end the line with ; symbol